# How do I configure rsyslog to write to /var/log/{hostname of sender} when receiving remote logs?

Tags: linux, networking, logging, syslog

My ADSL modem supports remote logging via syslog. I have set up my server, running rsyslog, to accept the log messages from the modem and they are being show in `/var/log/syslog` along with the messages generated on the server. The log looks like this:

```
(timestamp) (hostname) (program): (message)
```

Where hostname is either `server` or `modem`.

I've look over the (terrible, IMO) [documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/manual.html), and [found this example](http://www.rsyslog.com/storing-messages-from-a-remote-system-into-a-specific-file/) that looks like what I need, but I can't make it work in my situation.

How do I configure rsyslog to write the logs received from the modem to `/var/log/modem` instead of `/var/log/syslog`?

The modem IP is static, if that helps to simplify the answer.

**Moderators**: This post should probably have a `rsyslog` tag instead of `syslog`, but my reputation isn't high enough to create it.

Comment: If you are looking for a better documented and easier to configure syslog daemon, why not give [syslog-ng](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng) a spin? The [official documentation](http://www.balabit.com/support/documentation) is unrivaled in quality and the software itself works like a charm too.

Comment: @Janoszen, Thank you for the suggestion. I wasn't looking for a replacement, but lack of answers here may force a change. I presume it should be as easy as `apt-get remove rsyslog && apt-get install syslog-ng`?

Comment: actually it's just `apt-get install syslog-ng`. It will automatically remove rsyslog if I know correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple template to create one file for each host:

```
$template DynaFile,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%"
*.* -?DynaFile
```

Source: [How to separate log files by host name of sending device?](http://www.rsyslog.com/article60/)

I'm not sure if the right property to use in this case is 'hostname', 'source' or 'fromhost', but from my understanding of [the properties documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/properties.html) any of them will work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `rsyslog` then use a [`$template remote-incoming-logs`](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/templates.html#the-legacy-template-statement) declaration in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
$template remote-incoming-logs,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
*.* ?remote-incoming-logs
```

In case of your example, a login on host `modem` would send the log message to file `/var/log/modem/auth.log`.

Taken from this [article](https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-rsyslog-server-on-debian/).